# Overloading init with variable param number

Tags: objective-c, overloading

What is the proper way of overloading init methods with variable param number? I'm doing it:

```
- (id)initWithInt:(int)a
{
   return [self initWithInt:a andString:nil];
}


-(id)initWithInt:(int)a andString:(NSString*)str
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %i",str,a);
    }

    return self;
}
```

It works, but the `return [self initWithInt:a andString:nil];` does not seem right to me(there is no self at the moment, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is perfectly valid. Self is already setup, the idiom of reassigning self is for a couple of different edge cases (initialization fails, the initializer wants to return a different instance then the one you allocated, etc).

Comment: Just to clarify the "there is no self at the moment" statement, `self` does exists because it is the object returned by `alloc`. However, there is no guarantee that `self` is in a valid state until it is initialised, so expect that calling other methods will crash/fail and also expect that all the ivars will be zero'd memory.